# Como mostrar fechas en el eje horizontal de un gráfico en intérvalos de meses

Tags: excel

Estoy intentando configurar un eje horizontal de un gráfico, cuyos datos son diarios, que solo muestre etiquetas mensuales.

He encontrado este enlace que explica como hacerlo:
[Mostrar o cambiar las fechas en un eje de categorías](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/mostrar-o-cambiar-las-fechas-en-un-eje-de-categor%C3%ADas-d5a8146b-d457-43d1-8602-c1d23c96d650)

Sin embargo a mi no me aparecen esas opciones. En el enlace hay esta imágen de las propiedades:
[image: Opciones de eje según Microsoft]

Pero a mi me aparece esto:

[image: Opciones de eje que me aparecen]

Tengo un Microsoft Office Profesional Plus 2016 actualizado.

¿Alguna idea de porque no me sale igual?

Nota: He intentado hacerlo con VBA, pero tampoco cambia el eje:

```
Ch.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).CategoryType = xlTimeScale
Ch.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).BaseUnit = xlMonths
```

Comment: Prueba en la pestaña de etiquetas a de tus propiedades a especificar un intervalo de 30.

Comment: Lo había probado pero no funciona igual ya que no todos los meses tienen 30 días. Gracias de todos modos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionado.

El problema era que los datos venían de una consulta a otro fichero Excel, y ese fichero era generado por una aplicación que guardaba las fechas como texto.

Al importarlas, Excel las interpreta como texto y aunque definas las celdas como Fecha no las reconoce como tal.

Para solucionarlo hemos modificado la aplicación que genera Excel para que lo guarde como fecha.

Para solucionarlo manualmente se puede editar las casillas simplemente dando "Enter" en la barra de edición y ya cambia de formato texto (alineado a la izquierda) por formato fecha (alineado a la derecha)

[image: Captura Excel Fechas de Texto a Fecha]

Manualmente hay que hacerlo una a una.

Comment: Me alegro que pudieras solucionarlo. En 41h podrás marcar tu respuesta como aceptada. un saludo